# How to omit fields that will be filled in by the database

Tags: haskell, yesod

I've just started off with [Persistent from Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) and have already hit my first roadblock.

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
User
  email String
  createdAt UTCTime Maybe default=CURRENT_TIME
  updatedAt UTCTime Maybe default=CURRENT_TIME
  deriving Show
|]

u <- insert $ User "saurabhnanda@gmail.com" Nothing Nothing
```

I'm coming from a Rails background and like the schema design conventions advocated by them. In this particular case, having every table have a `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamp. However, is there any way to NOT specify the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields for every object that will be created?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you can always define a helper function that takes an email address and returns an `IO User` with the time fields populated (you'll need `IO` to grab the current time). An alternate solution: write a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Persistent, but the usual technique for this kind of thing is to define some parameterized types. For example, you might write

```
data Dated a = Dated
    { created :: UTCTime
    , updated :: UTCTime
    , value :: a
    }
```

Then your bare values need not worry about their metadata, and metadata can be handled uniformly across all different types. e.g. you might expose an API like this:

```
new :: a -> IO (Dated a)
new a = do
    now <- getUTCTime
    return (Dated now now a)

update :: Dated a -> a -> IO (Dated a)
update old new = do
    now <- getUTCTime
    return (old { updated = now, value = new })
```

Then I would suggest exporting the `Dated` type constructor and all its fields, together with `new` and `update`, but not exporting the `Dated` data constructor. This will ensure that the `created` and `updated` fields are maintained correctly.